# Get URL Parameters from referer

Tags: php, urls, settings-api

Not 100% sure if this one classes as a php question or is specifically Wordpress...

I'm implementing the Wordpress Settings API with a tabbed settings page. I've added a 'reset tab' button, but since the validation is done on a separate page (options.php) I can't seem to figure out which tab I'm on - without adding the tab as a hidden field, which I want to avoid.

I've found the `wp_get_referer()` function, but that gives me the full URL - I'm not sure how to pull the `tab=tab1` out as a variable.

**Update - Answer:**

```
$url = parse_url(wp_get_referer());
parse_str($url['query'], $path);
$tab = $path['tab'];
```

As said in the answers, some validation is then required.

Comment: You are doing this without Javascript?

Comment: Yep.

My form is located at `wordpress/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=967slug_settings_page&tab=tab3` (notice the tab parameter)
The settings_API then submits the form to `options.php` (Wordpress core) which then calls a validation function (written by me). I'm trying to get the value of the tab parameter within the validation function.

The wordpress function `wp_get_referer()` gives me the full URL (URI?) - exactly as above - but I'm not sure how to extract the value of 'tab' from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `tab=tab` is in the URL then:

```
global $_GET;
var_dump($_GET); // debugging only; You should be able to see what you need.
```

That is pure PHP. If your really need to process that string (I don't know why your would) use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) then use [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) on the `query` part of it.

```
$path = parse_url($url);
$path = parse_str($path, $output);
var_dump($output); // again, just debugging
```

For completeness, please don't use any of those values without [validating them](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation).

Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use `$_GET` as the URL I'm trying to take the parameter from is the referer not the current URL.

However, given that I can get access to the referer through the  `wp_get_referer` function, I think I can pull together something that uses `parse_url` and `parse_str` to get by tab parameter.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Just to close this down properly, I've been playing around with your suggestions to get an answer, which I've added to my original quesiton.

@s_ha_dum - thanks for the help.